# Angular resolver returns no data

Tags: angular, typescript

I cant make my resolver to work. The *data* object in the component is always empty. Any idea what's wrong?

Resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import {Operation} from "../model/operation.model";
import {OperationsService} from "../service/operations.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OperationsResolver implements Resolve<Operation[]> {

  constructor(private operationsService: OperationsService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Operation[]> {
    return this.operationsService.getAll();
  }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Operation} from "../model/operation.model";

const baseUrl = '/api/operation';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OperationsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAll(): Observable<Operation[]> {
    return this.http.get<Operation[]>(baseUrl);
  }
}
```

Routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {OperationsResolver} from "./resolver/operations.resolver";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'home',
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: { operations: OperationsResolver }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data);
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.operations = data['operations'];
      console.log(this.operations.length);
    });
  }
```

console.log(this.operations.length); throws error this.operations is undefined. The first and second log prints {}. No network errors, the API is called and returns an array of data as expected.

**Resolver** - Interface that classes can implement to be a data provider. A data provider class can be used with the router to resolve data during navigation. The interface defines a resolve() method that is invoked when the navigation starts. The router waits for the data to be resolved before the route is finally activated.

Comment: It should be a standard debugging exercise. Please explain what happens in your code. For example, do the log statements ever execute? Are their errors in the network tab of your browser devtools?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, console.log(this.operations.length); throws error this.operations is undefined. The first and second log prints {}
No network errors, the API is called and returns an array of data as expected.
So how does "the standard debugging" looks like in such a case?

Comment: The date of its being returned from your web server is not in the format that the angular client expects. This is standard debugging. We've been specific as to what the error is, clarifying the meaning of "returns no data", and determined how we must proceed